# How to set current value in jQuery UI date/time picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using `jQuery UI Date` picker with [Timepicker Addon](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon). I set 10 am as minimum date. Is it possible somehow without changing the time select `10:00:00` when clicking **done** button? Currently I can do it only if I change for example seconds to one and the reselect it.

[image]

Comment: how do you initialize the timepicker

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sqhyq1f8/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny // Set time picker
jQuery('.has-time-picker').timepicker({
 'timeFormat': 'HH:mm:ss',
 'controlType': 'select',
});

Comment: @ArunPJohny in yours example just open the picker and press done. Nothing happens.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sqhyq1f8/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny is it possible to set somehow like this `.timepicker('option', {'minTime': value, 'defaultValue': value})` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following options:

```
hour        //    Default: 0 - Initial hour set.
minute      //    Default: 0 - Initial minute set.
second      //    Default: 0 - Initial second set.
millisec    //    Default: 0 - Initial millisecond set.
```

You need to initialize this way:

```
$(element).datetimepicker({
    hour:       5,
    minute:     5,
    second:     0,
    millisec:   0
});
```